# Microsoft AzureのVirtual MachineはVPNで接続されたオンプレ環境のブロードキャストを受け取ることができるか。

Tags: azure, vpn

ご教授くださいませ。

ネットで探しても見つけることができなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきます。
Microsoft Azure上にVirtual MachineでWindowsを1インスタンス作成する予定です。
そのVMは、VPN Gatewayを介してローカル環境で通信しているブロードキャストを受け取りたいです。
このようなことは実現可能なのでしょうか。

私が参考にしたのは以下のページですが、明確な答えにたどり着けませんでした…

下記ページはVPN GatewayのFAQですが、ブロードキャストについては書かれていませんでした。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq

下記ページはVNetの内容ですが、こちらにはブロードキャストキャストが通信できないと記載がありました。(Azure上のVM間?)
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAQのページにある通り、Azure上のVirtual Machineが参加するVNETはブロードキャストを流さない（許可されない）ので受け取ることができません。